# Commutative algebra reference as a prerequisite to algebraic curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation, algebraic-curves

I am an M.Sc second year student of Mathematics.I have taken a one-semester project on 'Algebraic curves' under one of our faculty members.For that I need to learn some commutative algebra.I do not have much time to read entire commutative algebra and become a master of commutative algebra.I need as much as needed for learning 'Algebraic curves'.My guide has suggested me the book 'Algebraic curves' by W.Fulton.But,without knowing commutative algebra,he said,it will be difficult for me to understand those things.So,can someone tell me some good reference so that I can acquire the prerequisites of commutative algebra for the mentioned topic?

Comment: Seems "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah&Macdonald.

Comment: Try Algebraic geometry for scientists and engineers I often read the same As I am also learning it.